# android sql update not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite, content-values

This is how the table and row look like :

```
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
        "(" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_INSTANT +
        " TINYINT not null, " + COLUMN_CHANCE + " int not null);";

public static final String TABLE_INSERT = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        COLUMN_ID+"," + COLUMN_INSTANT +","+ COLUMN_CHANCE
        +") VALUES (" +
        "1," + "0," + "10"
        +");";
```

And this is how I try to update them :

```
try {
        open();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(column_name, value);
        database.beginTransaction();
        database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + whereClause,null);
        database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        database.endTransaction();
    }
    close();
```

The previous code would be equal to this query :

```
UPDATE options SET instant = 0 WHERE _id = 1
```

But the change is never applied. I check the table before and after the update but the values are the same, can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: what is passed to the param `whereClause`

Comment: "1" (and yes a row with id 1 exists, I checked before the update and then I check the same one afterwards)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make method to update...here is an example, change column name accordingly.

```
public int updateDetail(String new_name,String surname) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", new_name);
        return Db.update(TABLE_NAME ,values, SURNAME +"=?",new String[]{surname});
}
```